# How to initiate a session from celery signal?

Tags: python, python-requests, celery

Trying to init a `requests.Session()` from a function decorated with `@worker_init.connect`. That means the function is called by a celery signal.

Function simply looks like this:

```py
class MasterCelery(Celery):
    def __init__(
            self,
            *args,
            **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )

    @worker_init.connect
    def create_http_session(
            **kwargs
    ):
        # here create a session
        pass


    @worker_shutdown.connect
    def close_http_session(
            **kwargs
    ):
        logger.info("Closing HTTP session.")
        SESSION.close()
        logger.info("HTTP session closed.")
```

My actual Session setup is basically a module variable, that can be called from anywhere -

```py
from requests import Session

SESSION: Final = Session()
```

But my goal is to create this session variable, that I can use anywhere in the application, when the worker starts. How do I put these 2 things together? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to initialize a **Session** once for every celery worker process and using this **Session** inside your **task** functions then using [Custom Task Classes](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) would be the best choice.

**Example : Using Custom task classes directly**

```
from celery import Task
class SomeTaskThatUseSession(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        # this is called once per celery process
        self.session = requests.Session()
    def run(self, *args):
        # this is the code that will be run when calling this task
        return session.get(*args)
```

According to the *Celery Documentation*:

> A task is not instantiated for every request, but is registered in the
> task registry as a global instance. This means that the **init**
> constructor will only be called once per process.

**Example : Inheriting from custom task classes (preferred)**

```
from celery import Task
class PersistentSession(Task):
    _session = None
    @property
    def session(self):
        if self._session is None:
            self._session = requests.Session()
                return self._session
```

Then your tasks can use the session property by inheriting from
**PersistentSession** custom classe defined above

```
@app.task(base=PersistentSession)
def get_request(url):
    # you task (get_request) now act as an object that caches the session property / classe variable)
    get_request.session.get(url)
```